# CircleCI with Rails server and ember app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, capybara, circleci, nightly-build

I'm working on a Rails application, that uses ember as front-end framework for the client side within the application. I use Capybara on CircleCI to run the tests.

I have a lot of end-to-end tests, which make the build time very slow. I have found that the problem could be because it builds ember application for every spec file separately.

Is there anyone who knows if I can build the whole application once (somehow), and use that as the test server, to speed up the build.
Or some other method/suggestion to improve the speed of my build.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That would allow state from one test to affect a different test.  The whole purpose of tests is for them to be completely independent of each other so any one could be run separately and/or in any order.  If you really want multiple tests to run against the same page without clearing it out and reloading then you need to combine them all into one test.

Comment: I believe you misread what was desired. He was hoping to not rebuild his Ember app per file, which wouldn't keep state ...

Comment: exactly. Is it in anyway possible?